# Como separar em variáveis diferentes um arquivo com múltiplos FASTA

Tags: perl

Eu queria saber como posso colocar cada FASTA em uma variável diferente, sendo que todos estão no mesmo arquivo. Ou mesmo colocar em um *array* e recuperar cada um deles por números.

Cada Fasta se inicia com o símbolo de `>`, como no exemplo:

```
'>'Pvivax_1
AAGGTTT

'>'Pvivax_2
TTGGCCC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como em arquivos Fasta existem os cabeçalhos e os conteúdos suspeito que seria interessante para você mantê-los separados e recuperar o que quiser de cada um dos mesmos:

```py
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'arquivo.fasta';
open my $info, $file or die "Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo $file: $!";
@cabecalho = ();
@conteudo = ();
while( my $linha = <$info>)  { 
    if($linha =~ '>'){
       push(@cabecalho, $linha);
    }else{
       push(@conteudo, $linha);
    }   
    last if $. == 2;
}

close $info;
```

Depois para recuperar:

```
print $cabecalho[0];
```

Comment: (falta-nos uma especificação mais formal do formato e do pretendido mas) como relacionas o cabeçalho com o conteudo?

Answer (score 2):

Esse metodo e OK se o seu arquivo nao for muito grande:

```
sub ler_fasta {
    my %seqs;
    my $header;
    my $seq;
    open (IN, $arq) or die "abrir o arquivo falhou $arq: $!\n";
    while (<IN>) {
        if (/>/) {
            if ($seq) {
                $seqs{$header} = $seq;
            }

            $header =~ s/^>//; # remove o ">"
            $header =~ s/\s+$//; # remove espacos / tabs no final

            $seq = ""; # apaga a sequencia antiga
        }  else {
            s/\s+//g; # tira os espacos etc.
            $seq .= $_; # adiciona a nova sequencia
        }
    }
    close IN;

    if ($seq) { # a ultima sequencia
        $seqs{$header} = $seq;
    }

    return \%seqs; # retorna o array das sequencias
```

[Referencia](http://code.izzid.com/2011/10/31/How-to-read-a-fasta-file-in-perl.html).

Answer (score 1):

(Bem sei que esta pergunta é antiga, mas é tão raro coisas diferentes de html e js que eu não resisto...)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

sub ler_fasta { my $file=shift;
  local $/="'>'";        # separador de registo=  '>'
  my %val;

  open(FASTA, "fasta.txt") or die "Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo: $!";
  while( <FASTA>)  { chomp;
      if(/(.+)\n(.+)/){ $val{$1}=$2 }
  }
  return \%val
}
```

Deste modo os valores ficam associados ao identificador (Ex: `print $val->{Pvivax_1}`)

```
use Data::Dumper;    print Dumper( ler_fasta("fasta.txt"))
```

dá

```
$VAR1 = { 'Pvivax_2' => 'TTGGCCC',
          'Pvivax_1' => 'AAGGTTT'
        };
```

Comment: o problema em fazer isso com arquivos fasta é que a maioria deles (>80%) tem cabeçalhos irregulares, porque pela natureza destes arquivos pode estar escrito qualquer coisa lá. No entanto, acho válido manter sua resposta para ter mais exemplos de perl em Português.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun, obrigado pelo comentário, Falta-me uma definição do formato FASTA! Olhei para a wikipedia e o exemplo apresentado na nossa "questao" não está exatamente de acordo com o formato descrito na wikipedia...